# Magento2 - Widget with WYSIWYG editor

Tags: magento2, widget

I'm creating my own extension that adds a widget with a WYSIWYG-editor. I found a tutorial about this subject: http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/magento-2-add-wysiwyg-editor-text-area-in-custom-widget/.

This code does add a WYSIWYG editor, but it does not work well. It's buggy, for example:

- When I insert HTML, save the widget, reopen the widget the widget itself is added to the WYSIWYG editor of the widget.
- Update does not work at all.

What is the proper way to create a widget with WYSIWYG-editor?

Comment: Did you found any solution regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2.4 I fixed this by implementing it with a textarea and parse it afterwards with JS. I got inspired by core module: `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Helper\Form\Wysiwyg;`

```
    class Editor extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

    const TEXT_AREA_ID = 'stepsContentWidget';

    protected $_elementFactory;

    /**
     * @var SecureHtmlRenderer
     */
    protected $secureRenderer;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory,
        ?SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer = null,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->secureRenderer = $secureRenderer ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SecureHtmlRenderer::class);
        $this->_elementFactory = $elementFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare chooser element HTML
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element Form Element
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
     */
    public function prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $input = $this->_elementFactory->create("textarea", ['data' => $element->getData()]);
        $input->setId(self::TEXT_AREA_ID);
        $input->setForm($element->getForm());
        $input->setClass("widget-option input-textarea admin__control-text");
        if ($element->getRequired()) {
            $input->addClass('required-entry');
        }

        $element->setData('after_element_html', $input->getElementHtml() . $this->addAfterHtmlJs() . $this->getAfterElementHtmlCss());
        return $element;
    }

    public function addAfterHtmlJs()
    {
        $scriptString = <<<HTML
            require([
                'jquery',
                'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
            ], function(jQuery){
                wysiwygcompany_description = new wysiwygSetup('{$this->getHtmlId()}', {
                        "width":"100%%",  // defined width of editor
                        "height":"200px", // height of editor
                        "plugins":[], // for image
                        "tinymce4":{"toolbar":"formatselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link table charmap","plugins":"advlist autolink lists link charmap media noneditable table contextmenu paste code help table",
                     }
                 });
                 wysiwygcompany_description.setup("exact");
            });
        HTML;
        return $this->secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false);
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getAfterElementHtmlCss() {
        $html = <<<HTML
        <style>
            .admin__field-control.control .control-value {
                display: none !important;
            }
        </style>
        HTML;
        return $html;
    }


    public function getHtmlId()
    {
        return self::TEXT_AREA_ID;
    }
}
```